# How Dockerfile find references

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I would like to understand how both dockerfiles works. Specially when restoring project references.
The original dockerfile only has main project in copy, even this project has some dependecies. How are this dependencies restored?

**Original**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers 
COPY ["MyApplication.Api/MyApplication.Api.csproj", "MyApplication.Api/"]
 
RUN dotnet restore "MyApplication.Api/MyApplication.Api.csproj"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/app/MyApplication.Api"
RUN dotnet build "MyApplication.Api.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /app/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApplication.Api.dll"]
```

And this is the dockerfile generated by VisualStudio2022 when docker support is added. In this case it specifies all project references which makes sense to me.

**VS2022**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApplication.Api/MyApplication.Api.csproj", "MyApplication.Api/"]
COPY ["MyApplication.Common.Resources/MyApplication.Common.Resources.csproj", "MyApplication.Common.Resources/"]
COPY ["MyApplication/MyApplication.Common.Services/MyApplication.Common.Services.csproj", "MyApplication/MyApplication.Common.Services/"]
COPY ["MyApplication/MyApplication.Common.Domain/MyApplication.Common.Domain.csproj", "MyApplication/MyApplication.Common.Domain/"]
COPY ["MyApplication/MyApplication.Common.DataAccess/MyApplication.Common.DataAccess.csproj", "MyApplication/MyApplication.Common.DataAccess/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApplication.Api/MyApplication.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApplication.Api"
RUN dotnet build "MyApplication.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApplication.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApplication.Api.dll"]
```

So the exact question would be, how the first option solve references since those are not specified??

The thing is that some of my projects failed on AzureDevops pipelines since it does not find the references, but others work well with the "original" version and this does not make sense at all for me.

Comment: Please provide more information with the steps showing how to reproduce the problem you're seeing. It would be helpful to see a simplified project file that demonstrates the issue as well as the docker build output.

Comment: The thing is that both options build correctly, I just want to understand how "Original" solves project references, since they are not specified like in "VS2022" dockerfile. Only 1 csproj is specified ("Original") vs the 5 csproj on ("VS2022"), but both produce the same build.